# Render page with new data passed to flask from angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, python-3.x, flask

I'm trying to update my data on page on date change. I had used angularJS date picker for that and using flask on back-end. Now, When I pass changed date from angular to flask it generates the desired output but unable to get the updated data on html page. When I checked with `console.log(response)` it displayed whole updated html page as response in angular. I want this response to be displayed on page.Here's my code:

**Views.py**

```
        @app.route('/dI', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
        @login_required
        def dI():
        thirtydays = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(30)
        start = int(thirtydays.strftime("%s"))
        end = int(datetime.date.today().strftime("%s"))
        if request.method == 'POST':
            filter = request.get_json()
            if filter != None:
                startdate = int(time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(filter['startdate'], '%d/%m/%Y').timetuple()))
                enddate = int(time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(filter['enddate'], '%d/%m/%Y').timetuple()))
                return render_template('dI.html', hD=hD(), check_index=check_index(startdate, enddate))
        else:
            return render_template('dI.html', hD=hD(), check_index=check_index(start, end))
```

**AngularJS Code**

```
    var data = {
                    startdate:start,
                    enddate:end
                }
$http.post("/dI",data).success(function(response, status, headers, config) {
            console.log(response)
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

use the   [`ng-bind-html`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml)tag in your page. In any random template you can use it this way.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  {{test}} <!--will show '<p>test</p>'-->
  <div ng-bind="test"></div> <!--will show '<p>test</p>'-->
  <div ng-bind-html="test"></div> <!--will show 'test'-->
</div>
```

in the controller you should have something like this

```
$scope.test = "<p>test</p>";
```

Comment: I'm not binding data with angular. Data is directly getting bound through flask.